# Проблема с кодом

Tags: javascript

Весь код :

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script>
    alert('Начнём, игру')
    var goodgame = 0
        var quest =prompt('Идёт, мычит, качается...');

        if (quest == бык || quest == бычок) {
        alert('Это правильный ответ!');
        goodgame++
        } else {
        alert('Это неправильный ответ');
        }


            quest = prompt('Если б не было его, не сказал бы ничего.');

            if (quest == язык); {
            alert('О боже, как ты угадал ?!');
            goodgame++
            } else {
            alert('Ты не угадал')
            }


                quest = prompt('Кругом вода, а с питьем беда.');

                if (quest == море); {
                alert('Я в тебе не сомневался');
                goodgame++
                } else {
                alert('Ты не прав.');
                }


    alert('Твои правильные ответы' + goodgame)
    alert('Всего доброго, игра закончена кстати, можешь идти.')
</script>
```

Сама проблема :

```
quest = prompt('Если б не было, не сказал бы ничего.');
if (quest == язык); {
alert('О боже, как ты угадал ?!');
goodgame++
} else {
alert('Ты не угадал')
}
```

После фигурной скобки которая идёт сразу за "else" выдаёт ошибку , не могу понять в чём проблема, помогите пожалуйста.

Буду благодарен.

Comment: Не забудьте взять строки в кавычки, вот так: `"язык"`. Иначе браузер будет ругаться, что переменная «язык» не объявлена.

Answer (score 1):

У вас имеется опечатка.

```
if (quest == язык); {
                 ^^^
```

Уберите точку с запятой.

То же самое относится и к этому предложению

```
if (quest == море); {
                 ^^^
```

И строковые литералы следует заключить в кавычки.

Comment: И после `goodgame++` точка с запятой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в этом случае сам проставит